# Jquery Input Date Array Selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I have errors in the code shown below. I want to have a validation on age, and  the problem is only the first element compute the age.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<label class="control-label" for="fam_name">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fam_name[]" id="fam_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<label class="control-label" for="fam_bdate">Birthdate:</label>
<input type="date" name="fam_bdate[]" id="fam_bdate" class="form-control fam_bdate" required>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5">
<label class="control-label" for="fam_name">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fam_name[]" id="fam_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<label class="control-label" for="fam_bdate">Birthdate:</label>
<input type="date" name="fam_bdate[]" id="fam_bdate" class="form-control fam_bdate" required>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
$('input[name^="fam_bdate"]').each(function() {
   $(this).blur(function() {
   var birth = new Date($(this).val());
   var today = new Date();
   var age = Math.floor((today-birth) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

   console.log(age);
   });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: didn't work, thanks

Comment: The better way to accomplish this would be to reference by class instead, so $('input.fam_bdate')

Comment: Also, you have a duplicated id in your form, id="fam_bdate". IDs have to be unique, or they will cause issues.

Comment: @sterling, carat means start with not `not`. See https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: still, btw i've change the element id="fam_bdate1" and id="fam_bdate2". still the only first element compute its age.

Comment: @Satpal wow, my bad, it's getting late, I'm gonna delete that!